# Javascript Onchange formatting

Tags: php, javascript, html

How do I put 2 options in the following onchange?

Meaning I would like the end of it to be something like this: `Select(select_2,'divShow',1-2);`

So either the first or second option in a dropdown will trigger the JS

```
    onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();Select(select_2,'divShow',2);
```

HTML as requested by Lee
Please note the ID's are all generated by magento so it adds a slight level of difficulty.

```
            <select name="options[7]" id="select_7" class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title=""
onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();Select(select_7,'divShow',2);">
<option value="" >-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="18" >No </option>
<option value="19" >Yes </option></select>
```

Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function Select(sel,id,nu){
document.getElementById(id).style.display=sel.selectedIndex==nu?'block':'none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't even use inline JS... that's how.

Comment: I don't understand I was told in another post this is what I needed to  do in order to hide a field until a option is selected fro mthe drop down. If you can tell me another way to hide a field unless any option from the drop down is selected I would be greatful.

Comment: Or is there a wildcard I could put in there? instead of a number?

Comment: I think you need to show us your HTML too.

Comment: I have a lot going on with it I will post it but please bear with my mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work :) I made the following changes.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
function Select(sel,id,nu){
document.getElementById(id).style.display=sel.selectedIndex!==nu?'block':'none';
}
</script>
```

and

```
    onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();Select(select_2,'divShow',0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The safer way to do this would be the following.

```
var eventListener = function(el, type, listener) {
    if(el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
    } else if(el.attatchEvent) {
        el.attatchEvent("on"+type, listener);
    } else {
        el["on"+type] = listener;
    }
};

var element = document.getElementById("el-ID"); //some kind of reference to your element

eventListener(element, "change", function() {
    opConfig.reloadPrice();
    Select(select_2,'divShow',2);
});
```